# 3D Print Addon Miscalculating Volumes

Tags: add-on, transforms

This doesn't occur consistently but enough for me to notice. I have Applied Transform /All and reset origin to geometry to no effect. The dimensions on this example are correct and correlate with edge dimensions as they appear in *Edit Mode*.

This is a bit of deal breaker for me as I'm using this for concrete volumes in a real world scenario.

I am aware of the scale mismatch but the result is off by a factor other than 10 so that is not the issue. If there's a better and equally simple method to determine a correct result I'm all eyes.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, can't reproduce your error... I create a cuboid with these dimensions, the volume shows 12.992 mm³ as it should. Did you make sure there are no decimals other than the ones shown in the dimensions? If you click on one of those values to edit it, are they exact? For example, if you click on 20.3 mm, there could be 20.34 mm and it would still show 20.3 if you leave the field. Or did you change any values and the volume calculation is not refreshed? If you change values and don't click the _Volume_ button afterwards, the displayed volume isn't refresehd and show an old value.

Comment: Thanks - your comment triggered me to use the Checks function ( Solids ) and it reported non-manifold geometry. Using the Clean Up function fixed this and then the volume calculation returned a proper result.